# How to append text pending on checkbox state?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, append, state, text-files

I’m making a form with a checkbox where if checked a target file is appended with text-A and if Unchecked the file is appended with text-B

How can I do this?

what i have sofar:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_Checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.Checked
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\ANSWERSLIST.txt"

    'Adding items for AutoCAD 2006...
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
        objWriter.WriteLine("YES")
        objWriter.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx) method:

```
If MyCheckBox.IsChecked Then
    File.AppendAllText("foo.txt", "text-A")
Else
    File.AppendAllText("foo.txt", "text-B")
End If
```

Comment: what is the file declared as?

Comment: It might seam a little odd but Im a newbie to VB.net and now my VB.net is saying Name 'file' is not declared?

Comment: @rick, you might need to `import System.IO` in your module.

Comment: I can nomaly use any other System.IO function its probably my own codeing im getting wrong